# Filter data to keep only the last day of the month

Tags: r, date

I have daily data from which I'd like to extract the **last day of every month**.

Original data:

```
         Date    Value
20 2008-01-28 82.55261
21 2008-01-29 83.43333
22 2008-01-30 83.07948
23 2008-01-31 84.22759
24 2008-02-01 85.77670
25 2008-02-04 84.87240
26 2008-02-05 82.58407
27 2008-02-06 81.77103
28 2008-02-07 80.78428
29 2008-02-08 81.51842
30 2008-02-11 82.39453
31 2008-02-12 84.09175
32 2008-02-13 85.58366
33 2008-02-14 83.77604
```

Desired output:

```
##         Date    Value
## 1 2008-01-31 84.22759
## 2 2008-02-14 83.77604
```

Data was kindly put together by G. Grothendieck from a screenshot posted in the earliest version of this question:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(13906, 13907, 13908, 13909, 
13910, 13913, 13914, 13915, 13916, 13917, 13920, 13921, 13922, 
13923), class = "Date"), Value = c(82.552612, 83.433327, 83.079483, 
84.227585, 85.776695, 84.872398, 82.584068, 81.771027, 80.784279, 
81.518417, 82.39453, 84.091751, 85.583664, 83.776039)), row.names = c("20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This question gets quite a high search hit. It was originally very poorly formatted. I have edited it substantially. Is it good enough to be reopened? There is a good answer by G. Grothendieck that would benefit from being read more. If this question gets reopened, here is yet another answer based on ``dplyr`` and very intuitive steps: https://pastebin.com/zP1ZcgNf

Comment: @PatrickT an important (and good) question. I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

I have OCR'd the image in the question using the tesseract R package and manually fixed up the errors it produces but in the future please provide the input in a form that can be directly copied and pasted into R.  If `DF` is the input cut down to appropriate size then the output of `dput(DF)` can be used. See Note at end of this answer.

Here are two approaches:

**1) substr**  This one-liner takes the first 6 characters of the date (i.e. year and month) and uses that to find the last row in each group so formed.  No packages are used.

```
subset(DF, !duplicated(substr(V1, 1, 6), fromLast = TRUE))
##          V1       V2
## 23 20080131 84.22759
## 33 20080214 83.77604
```

**2) yearmon** Another possibility is to use yearmon class (in the zoo package).  A yearmon object only has year and month (no day) so it naturally forms year/month groups and we take the last of each.

```
library(zoo)

subset(DF, !duplicated(as.yearmon(as.character(V1), "%Y%m"), fromLast = TRUE))
##          V1       V2
## 23 20080131 84.22759
## 33 20080214 83.77604
```

#### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(V1 = c(20080128L, 20080129L, 20080130L, 20080131L, 
20080201L, 20080204L, 20080205L, 20080206L, 20080207L, 20080208L, 
20080211L, 20080212L, 20080213L, 20080214L), V2 = c(82.552612, 
83.433327, 83.079483, 84.227585, 85.776695, 84.872398, 82.584068, 
81.771027, 80.784279, 81.518417, 82.39453, 84.091751, 85.583664, 
83.776039)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c("20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
"33"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df$mon_yr = format(df$date, "%Y-%m") 
# creates an identifier with which to group

df %>% group_by(mon_yr) %>% filter(date == max(date))
#groups by created month identifier and then keeps only those rows with last(max) date
```

Comment: @MZaragoza, the `df$mon_yr = format(df$date, "%Y-%m")` line creates an identifier with which to group. The `group_by(mon_yr)` does the requisite grouping, and then we keep (`filter`) only those rows which corresponds to the last (`max`) date.

Answer (score -3):

You are not giving us a sample of data nor a sample of code - hence the downvotes.

**1.** make sure your data is a `data.frame` (see ?data.frame in R)

```
df <- myexcelfile # Pseudocode - will not run!
```

**2.** make sure V1 is the date column. Make sure that you code it as a date (see ?as.Date in R).

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d%m%Y")
```

**3.** Filter the data Frame for the earliest date:

```
df[which.max(df$Date),]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. yeah of course i know, it was my first Question in R and also in programming, so i need to learn which informations you need to help me and i need to improve the way i ask questions on this topic :)

Comment: No worries - i hope you found a way to solve your Problem.